# Client Side Validation before sending data to server ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view in ASP.Net . I have added some controls in the view. I am trying to do client side validation before sending the data to server. If everything is fine, I want to send it to server.
**My code is here:**

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "staff", FormMethod.Post))
            {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <div> @Html.LabelFor(a => a.staff_name, "Staff Name")</div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.staff_name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "", required = "required", autofocus = "autofocus"})
            </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <div> @Html.LabelFor(a => a.user_name, "Username")</div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.user_name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "", required = "required" })

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <div> @Html.LabelFor(a => a.password, "Password")</div>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "", required = "required",id="password" })

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <div> @Html.LabelFor(a => a.confirm_password, "Confirm Password")</div>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.confirm_password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "", required = "required", id = "c_password" })

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right" onsubmit="validateForm()">Submit</button>
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
        }
    </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var c_pass = document.getElementById("c_password").value;

        if(pass==c_pass)
        {
            //submit
        }

    }

</script>
```

I want to check if 'password' and 'confirm password' matches or not.If yes, then only post in the server.

Comment: you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473848/3089009

Comment: did my answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should enable Client side validation with `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }` before `@Html.BeginForm` and use jquery `validate()`

use this to activate client side validation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#yourFormId").validate({
                rules: {
                    ConfirmPassword: {
                        equalTo: "#Password"
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                     confirm_password: {
                        equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                    },
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you just need to enable Client side validation in your web.config file there is no need of writing any external code for that.
You can add the below line of code in your web.config file

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Hope it works for you !

Comment: I have already these codes in web.config file. What I want is let Javascript validate the input .  After validation only, submit the data to server.